# Achieving same effect on a play button as show in this image

Tags: shapes, perspective, depth

as you can see in image the rectangle has this boxy look, I was trying to get same look on my play button, but it always turned out wrong, can anyone please edit the image and give that play button same boxy look? or at least reference somewhere where it show's how its done.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because of the lights in your 3D effect, your triangle will only have one dark line. This is what probably confused you, because it doesn't look very "boxy", but imagine the shape is casting a shadow. If lights come from the upper left corner, the only shadow you will see is this:

[image]

Comment: Oh right, I was experimenting with 2 shadow lines and could not get it right, thank you.